# Can I configure or minimize CSS isolation bundled file in Razor Pages? [ASP.NET Core 6.0]

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I want my bundled css file "~/MyRazorPagesApp.styles.css", which is created by css isolation, to be minimized.

I am using [Web Compiler 2022+](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Failwyn.WebCompiler64), which compiles and minimizes my .scss files, but the bundled file only includes the non-optimized ones.

I have this structure:

```
Index.cshtml
Index.cshtml.scss
Index.cshtml.css
Index.cshtml.min.css
```

but as I said, the outcome of css isolation is not optimized.

Can I somehow configure it to use "min.css" files, or minimize the whole css file after? In my local development I can't even see this file in wwwroot directory.

Answer (score 3):

Css isolation  can only find .css, not min.css. So your bundled css file "~/MyRazorPagesApp.styles.css" only includes the non-optimized ones. And 'MyRazorPagesApp.styles.css' is dynamically generated，so in your local development your can't even see this file in wwwroot directory.

If you want to use "min.css" files, you can put  "min.css" files into the Web Root (wwwroot) folder and add reference  like  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/Index.cshtml.min.css"  />` into _layout.cshtml .

Another solution refer to [Bundle and minify static assets in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-6.0), ASP.NET Core is compatible with WebOptimizer, an open-source bundling and minification solution . You can refer [WebOptimizer](https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer) to minimize the  css file( non-optimized ones) and bind.

For example:

In programs, bundle `/css/site.css` and `/css/Index.cshtml.min.css` into a single output file `/Indexcshtml.min.css`

```
builder.Services.AddWebOptimizer(pipeline =>
{
    pipeline.AddCssBundle("/Indexcshtml.min.css", "/css/site.css", "/css/Index.cshtml.min.css");
});

//...
app.UseWebOptimizer();
```

Besides,  the link reference goes in the layout file, just like other global style sheet refer,you also need to add add reference  like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="Indexcshtml.min.css" />` into _layout.cshtml.

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that works, but unfortunately I lose css isolation id attributes when just bundling .min.css files. Looks like there's no "perfect way" to handle this. Also I believe the support for LigerShark.WebOptimizer.Sass has been dropped, so I am forced to compile .scss with WebCompiler, and bundle .min.css with WebOptimizer - it's a little bit confusing.